# Load CSV data as RDF using Ontorefine CLI

Tags: csv, rdf, graphdb

I'm trying to programmatically add a csv file that's generated everyday to a GraphDB repository. I have already created the CSV to RDF mapping using Ontorefine. How does one use the CSV and the mapping now to add RDF triples programmatically.

Comment: Did you try to use [GraphDB API](https://graphdb.ontotext.com/free/devhub/workbench-rest-api/curl-commands.html) to upload RDF data?

Comment: I did look at the API. However the API doesn't support csv imports. Ontorefine does have a CLI interface. But ran into errors related to csrf tokens expected. I finally managed to replicate the Ontorefine process by reading the network calls. This isn't documented though.

Answer (score 1):

Use the open source CLI https://github.com/Ontotext-AD/ontorefine-client (that's probably what @aksanoble refers to).

Please note that the CLI is not yet available in Ontotext Refine 1.0 (which was split off from GraphDB), and will be available in September. In the meantime, you could use GraphDB 9.11.

We are working on extended ETL pipeline scenarios, including

- Reuse of cleaning and transformation scripts between projects
- Run all cleaning, transformation and RDF data update or download steps on a new dataset automatically

BTW, is your file stored locally or accessed through a URL? We have an idea to handle the latter case specially.